# How do I enable SASS lineNumbers with Yeoman's Grunt.js file?

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, yeoman-generator, line-numbers

I recently scaffolded a new webapp with Yeoman (1.4.5). In my Gruntfile.js I have set the following config:

```
...

// Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
sass: {
  options: {
    lineNumbers:true,
    sourceMap: true,
    includePaths: ['bower_components']
  }
...
```

Even though Grunt (grunt-cli v0.1.13) handles my instructions without errors and everything is running smoothly, unfortunately no SASS line numbers are showing up in my compiled CSS files? 
Am I missing something or is this an issue with the grunt-sass node package? I would like to keep my automated task instructions centralized in my gruntfile.js.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The right option is:

```
sourceComments: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [grunt-sass documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass), it looks like the option are only passed to `node-sass` directly. Add it doesn't looks like node-sass support these options - or not in the way you've written it.

I'd suggest reading the documentation to figure out the correct way to pass these arguments https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options